# Dynamically add key binding in polymer

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-shortcuts, web-component, polymer-2.x

I am using **IronA11yKeysBehavior** to implement keyboard shortcut handling in my project. I have a polymer element `<my-element></my-element>` in which I have defined the `keyBindings` property as follows

```
keyBindings : {
    'shift+a' : '_onKeyPreseed'
}
```

The element is working as expected. But I want to dynamically assign keyboard shortcuts (so that a user can change the shortcuts as per her requirements). Say I want to change the shortcut from `shift+a` to `alt+a`. How to do this?

I have changed the 'keyBindings' property, but that is not working, still `_onKeyPreseed` is called when `shift+a` is pressed, not when `alt+a`is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

Due to the [Documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/@polymer/iron-a11y-keys-behavior/behaviors/IronA11yKeysBehavior#method-addOwnKeyBinding) of IronA11yKeysBehavior it has a method `addOwnKeyBinding(eventString: string, handlerName: string): void` which allows to add keybindings at a later time.